# CSS absolute positioned div affected by sibling

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

I have this example http://jsfiddle.net/4cu8m/

```
<div id="main1">
    <div id="inner1"</div>    
    <div id="inner2"</div>    
</div>
```

The CSS positioning for `inner1` & `inner2` are exactly identical. They are absolute positioned inside `main1` - a relative positioned element. If I change the `left` co-ordinates for `inner1`, it shifts `inner2` also. I thought the absolute positioning is relative to first non-static parent element.

```
    #main1 {            
        position: relative;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        background-color: #f00;
        opacity:0.7;
    }
    #inner1 {            
        position: absolute;
        height: 100px;
        width: 30px;
        left : 10px;
        background-color: #0f0;
        opacity:0.7;
    }
    #inner2 {            
        position: absolute;
        height: 100px;
        width: 30px;
        left : 10px;
        background-color: #00f;
        opacity:0.7;
    }
```

Got this [image] instead of [image]

Comment: please correct your html div tag...u give wrong code on under the <div id="main1">

Comment: That's what @Fags wrote in the answer below. Thanks.

Comment: sorry please ignore...:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LIke this

```
please close div tag
```

**html**

```
<div id="main1">
    <div id="inner1"></div>    
    <div id="inner2"></div>    
</div>
```